# git clone git@bitbucket.org:... auto core.fileMode true

Tags: git

I try setup ignore filemode changes in my repositories

i see in

```
more .git/config 
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
```

i need

```
core.fileMode=false
```

when i clone repository. When i change it localy - there is no changes for push. So when i clone in other system i get

```
core.fileMode=true
```

Can I setup this as default for my repository ?

I have

```
git config --global core.fileMode false
```

(I use install when docker build and need change permission for editing)

Comment: This option controls only the executable bit, not other file permissions.  Are you trying to ignore just changes to the executable bit (and if so, why is that especially a problem in Docker) or adjust file permissions in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core.filemode` (whether spelled this way or as `core.fileMode`) *is not a user setting* and in general **you** *should not change it*.  There are, however, some special cases where may wish to *temporarily* change it, to make Git behave technically-incorrectly but usefully, but you need to know exactly what you are doing when you do this.

You mention:

> When i change [core.filemode] locally - there is no changes for push

That is because the `core.filemode` setting is irrelevant to `git push`.  It only matters for how Git resolves the differences, if any, between the modes stored in Git's index and the modes stored in your working tree.  The `git push` operation sends *commits* to some other Git, and by the time files are stored in a commit, their mode is set forever to whatever was stored in Git's index at commit time.  See the long description below.

> when i clone in other system ...

The `git clone` command sets `core.filemode` *based on the behavior of the computer* at the time the `git clone` creates the new empty repository.  (Remember that `git clone` runs `git init`, and see the long description below.)

> (I use install when docker build and need change permission for editing)

Write permissions for files are independent of `core.filemode` settings.

#### Long

What `core.filemode` does is *tell Git how your computer behaves*.  Changing the value stored in `core.filemode` does not change how your computer behaves, just as drawing a new road on a map does not cause the new road to appear in reality.

Specifically, on Linux systems and similar, some files are called *executable* and some are called *not executable*.  A not-executable file cannot be run as a command, and an executable file can be (though here the actual *content* needs to make sense as well).  To make a non-executable file become executable on a Linux system, one uses the `chmod` command (not a Git command):

```
chmod +x somefile
```

and now:

```
./somefile
```

will try to run the *contents* of `somefile` as a command, or series of commands.  To mark the same file as not-executable one uses:

```
chmod -x somefile
```

and now:

```
./somefile
```

just tells you that the file cannot be run (`./somefile: Permission denied` or similar).

When Git makes a new commit, Git records the executable-ness of each file-to-be-stored-in-the-commit, as indicated by the *mode* stored in Git's index.<sup>1</sup>  If you run:

```
git ls-files --stage
```

Git will print out, for every file in Git's index, the stored mode.  This is always either `100644` ("chmod -x") or `100755` ("chmod +x").<sup>2</sup>

Some computer *file systems*, however, either do not store modes at all—this is true for some very old Windows file systems, for instance—or store them erratically.  This is why [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) mentions this about `core.filemode`:

> [`core.filemode`] Tells Git if the executable bit of files in the working tree is to be honored.
>
> Some filesystems lose the executable bit when a file that is marked as executable is checked out, or checks out a non-executable file with executable bit on. [git-clone[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) or [git-init[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init) probe the filesystem to see if it handles the executable bit correctly and this variable is automatically set as necessary.
>
> A repository, however, may be on a filesystem that handles the filemode correctly, and this variable is set to `true` when created, but later may be made accessible from another environment that loses the filemode (e.g. exporting ext4 via CIFS mount, visiting a Cygwin created repository with Git for Windows or Eclipse). In such a case it may be necessary to set this variable to `false`. See [git-update-index[1]](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index).
>
> The default is true (when core.filemode is not specified in the config file).

When `core.filemode` is set to `true`, Git believes that your OS correctly handles the executable bit (as standard Linux file systems do).  Hence if, after extracting some commit, a later Git operation discovers that a *working tree* file has a different executable status than the *recorded index mode*, Git considers the working-tree file to be "modified".  A `git add` operation will update the stored mode.  But when `core.filemode` is set to `false`, Git believes that the OS incorrectly turns the executable bit on or off, more or less at random, so after extracting some commit, the working tree file mode is *ignored* and the index mode is retained.

To change the *index* mode when using such a system, use `git update-index` with the `--chmod` option.  Or, you *can* change `core.filemode` *temporarily*.  When you do so, Git will start believing the results from `lstat` system calls—so you need to know how those behave on your computer.  After you have done whatever you will do with this, you should generally *restore* the old `core.filemode` setting so that Git knows how your computer actually behaves.

(There is one other special case here, and that occurs when you can *change how your computer behaves*, e.g., with mount-time options.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Remember that Git actually builds new commits from what is in Git's *index*, rather than what is in your working tree.  Usually by the time you run `git commit` you have run the appropriate `git add` commands that make Git's index *match* your working tree.

<sup>2</sup>Symbolic links in Git's index are represented as mode `120000` and gitlinks, which are how submodules work, are represented as mode `160000`.  The index cannot store directories—entities with mode `040000`—which is why Git is unable to [store an empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1256452), although [an empty submodule actually does work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58543445/1256452) for this purpose.